# Printing Multiple Variables of a Python Class

Tags: python, class, variables

For Code:

```
class Car(object):
   def __init__(self, make, model, year, color, engine_type):
     self.make = make
     self.model = model
     self.year = year
     self.color = color
     self.engine_type = engine_type

main():
  car1 = Car('Ford', 'Mustang', '2001', 'Red')
  print car1.make, car1.model, car1.year, car1.color
```

Is there a better/shorter way to print multiple variables (but not all of them such as using vars() or __dict__) from a class? Something like...

```
print car1.[make, model, year, color]
```

but that actually works?

Comment: You can do: `print car1.make, car1.model, car1.year, car1.color`

Comment: Consider `pprint.pprint` or `getattr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something tricky like this:

```
attrs = ['make', 'model', 'year', 'color']
print " ".join(map(lambda attr: getattr(car1, attr), attrs))
```

I don't know if that's any better than what you have, though.

Comment: Sounds like there's no shorthand for it, but the above code taught me lots thanks! Never have seen lambda or map before, I've only been coding for about 3 months